# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NoEntryPointError: Extension 'cogs.help' has no 'setup' function

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am attempting to make a cog for my Discord Bot.

However, attempting to load the cog prompts me with the error

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NoEntryPointError: Extension 'cogs.help' has no 'setup' function.
```

The code for my loader is;

```py
@bot.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    id = str(ctx.author.id)
    if id == '721029142602056328':
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
        print(f'Specified cog {extension} loaded!')
        author = ctx.message.author

        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 237, 76)
        )

        embed.add_field(name='Cog Loaded', value=f"Specified cog {extension} loaded by {author}.", inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 237, 76)
        )

        embed.add_field(name="You can't do this!", value=f"You can't load the {extension} cog.", inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    id = str(ctx.author.id)
    if id == '721029142602056328':
        bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
        print(f'Specified cog {extension} unloaded!')
        author = ctx.message.author

        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 237, 76)
        )

        embed.add_field(name='Cog Unloaded', value=f"Specified cog {extension} unloaded by {author}.", inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 237, 76)
        )

        embed.add_field(name="You can't do this!", value=f"You can't unload the {extension} cog.", inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

If anyone could solve my error it would be greatly appreciated. It is also of note I can start the bot however I must remove "for file name in os.listdir..."

Thanks

## EDIT

I have just realized I forgot to include the code to my cog upon making this post.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Help(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Help(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an indentation issue.

Please make sure the setup function is aligned to the `__init__`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Help(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    def setup(bot):
        bot.add_cog(Help(bot))
```

Comment: ```
py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my user\Desktop\Discord Bot Coding\my bot\bot.py", line 217, in <module>
    bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
  File "C:\Users\my user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 651, in load_extension
    raise errors.ExtensionNotFound(name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'cogs.fun' could not be loaded.
```

Comment: 1. It means the setup issue is fixed as far as I can see. 2. cogs.fun seems to mean you have a fun.py in your directory. The code in the file is invalid and is causing the error.

Comment: I do not have a fun.py in my [directory.](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/760584123780956185/767428893438246912/unknown.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the error.

There were 2 of my bots in 1 folder called Discord Bot Coding, so it was reading from one of my bot's cog folder instead of the intended bot